# A whole class diagram for Cocoa Foundation Framework?

Tags: cocoa

Is there any PDF formatted whole class diagram for Cocoa Foundation Framework?

I found [a link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/ObjC_classic/FoundationObjC.pdf), and [another link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/ObjC_classic/Intro/IntroFoundation.html), but not being able to find a nice one.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also [Application Kit Classes and Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/ObjC_classic/Intro/IntroAppKit.html),

but either way: it's pretty comprehensive list of classes.. i.e. not something you're likely to print out and put on the whiteboard (or even the office wall) - in a readable font size, that is.

There was also some demo app shown at some WWDC that would use the Obj-C runtime to create a navigable class tree of some kind with all Cocoa or AppKit classes. Failed to find that particular example just now, though.

Comment: Sounds like you're thinking of [TreeView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/TreeView/), from "Crafting Custom Cocoa Views" at WWCD 2010.